# How Do I Query 2 Different Azure Directories When Using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am configuring my infrastructure in one Azure Directory with terraform and so I have set the Azure CLI to use that subscription:

```
az account set --subscription xxxxxxxx-0000-xxxx-YYYY-zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Part of the setup is to add Active Directory Groups to APIM Management.

I create the groups and query AD for their ids using az cli in `local-exec`.

However, Active Directory is in a different subscription to where the infrastructure is being created so this step fails.

How can I switch directory/subscription for this one call?

Comment: If the different subscriptions in the same tenant? or the different?

Comment: They are different tenants/directories *not* different subscriptions within a single tenant/directory

Answer (score 0):

> I create the groups and query AD for their ids using az cli in local-exec.

You can query for groups with datasource [azuread_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/d/group.html) and/or manage resource [azuread_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/group.html) instead of `az cli`.

To use datasource/resource with multiple subscriptions you should authenticate [multiple providers with aliases](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances) with different `subscription_id` like that:

```
provider "azuread" {
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxx-0000-xxxx-YYYY-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
}

provider "azuread" {
  subscription_id = "another-subscription-id"
  alias           = "custom"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "test" {
...
}

resource "azuread_group" "mygroup" {
  provider = azuread.custom
  name     = "my-group"
}
```